# Java regex find all occurences of a word inside double quotes

Tags: java, regex

[this](https://regex101.com/r/IohlS8/1) is my regex, I'm trying to find all occurences of string "variant" inside double quotes using this regex, but if there are 2 occurences inside double quotes it will take only the last one. My regex basically tries to find the string "variant" which is written inside double quotes, I tried writing it like this but it didn't work either: `\\".*(variant*).*\\"` This is my code:

```
String str_regex = "\\".*(variant).*\\"";
Matcher str_matcher = Pattern.compile(str_regex).matcher(joined);
while(str_matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(str_matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Why do you extract a known word? Are you counting matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I want to count the total number of occurences of the word, "variant" in this case, in the text.

Comment: You need to extract all matches with `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"` regex and then find all occurrences of `variant` inside those matches, there is no way with a single regex here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all occurrences of the strings inside double quotes and then count the `variant` occurrences inside the  matches:

```java
String s = "variant \"if and only if 5 divides by i without remainder, then it prints \\\"i + \\\" variant: \\\" + variant\\\"\" variant";

        
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()){
    count += matcher.group().split("variant", -1).length-1;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IWn4AU). So, the `variant "if and only if 5 divides by i without remainder, then it prints \"i + \" variant: \" + variant\"" variant` string contains two occurrences of `variant`.

The regex is `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/IohlS8/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more double backslashes
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`  - zero or more sequences of any escaped char and then zero or more chars other than `\` and `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.

Comment: it works, but it founds only 2 occurences , instead of 8 of string `"variant"` in this example: https://regex101.com/r/SYiBDH/1

Comment: @Javadkhan [It works and finds all 8 `variant` occurrences](https://ideone.com/D3toKy).

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, sorry I had a mistake in my code. Thanks for your help!